# How to distribute the source of a Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, open-source, project, software-distribution

I want to distribute the Visual Studio project source I have made, but I am not sure how to do it.

I have a project with a file structure as follows:

```
SimpleProject --
                |- .vs --
                         |- SimpleProject --
                                            |- v15 --
                                                     |- .suo
                                                     |- Browse.VC.db
                |- SimpleProject --
                                   |- file.c
                                   |- SimpleProject.vcxproj
                                   |- SimpleProject.vcxproj.filters
                                   |- SimpleProject.vcxproj.user
                |- SimpleProject.sln
```

All I have written is the `file.c`. What at a minimum do I need to include with `file.c` (assuming I want others to be able to use the source/compile it, etc. in Visual Studio)?

Comment: How is this too broad?  I simply want to know what to include with a VS project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough to share the following files, so others can build your project without any problems.

```
SimpleProject --
                |- SimpleProject --
                                   |- file.c
                                   |- SimpleProject.vcxproj
                                   |- SimpleProject.vcxproj.filters
                |- SimpleProject.sln
```

Before submitting/checking the code, I recommend you try if generated files are required to build and run the application. If not, you should not include them.

Comment: Happy to help :) 
But I saw post from Andrew. I think that is even better solution are you using Github or git distribute your project?

Comment: Yes I am using `Github` currently.  I may use other means later idk.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GitHub or what they recomend remove.
See the official GitHub's ["Collection of useful *.gitignore* templates"](https://github.com/github/gitignore).

The `.gitignore` for Visual Studio can be found here:
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore